# Linux "ls -al" like program in C

Tags: c, linux, ls

I have for homework to write a C program, which is acting like the Linux "ls -al" command. I know that there are a lot of example programs over the internet, which are doing the thing that I need, but I have a specific problem, to which I can't find a solution. I also want to mention, that I am new to C programming. Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pwd.h> 

int list_dir(const char *dirname)     { 

struct dirent* current_directory;
struct stat my_stat;
struct tm lt;  
struct passwd *pwd; // For User-ID

DIR* directory = opendir(dirname);


    if(directory == NULL)     { 

    printf("list_dir : %s : %s \n", dirname, strerror(errno));

    return 0;
}   

    printf("Directory : %s\n", dirname);
    printf("\n");

    while( (current_directory = readdir(directory) ) )     { 

    stat(current_directory->d_name, &my_stat);  

        if ( (stat(current_directory->d_name, &my_stat) ) == 0 )    {

        pwd = getpwuid(my_stat.st_uid); // Get User-ID

    }

        // Last Modified 
        time_t t = my_stat.st_mtime;
        localtime_r(&t, &lt);
        char timebuf[80];
        strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%c", &lt);

        if (pwd != 0) {

        printf("%s \t %ld \t %s \t %s", pwd->pw_name, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, current_directory->d_name);
        printf("\n");

        } else  {

            printf("%d \t %ld \t %s \t %s", my_stat.st_uid, (long)my_stat.st_size, timebuf, current_directory->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        } 
}
    closedir(directory);        

    return 0; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    {

    if ( argc == 1 ) {

    return list_dir ( "." );

    } else {

    int ret = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i += 1 ) {

        if ( list_dir ( argv[i] ) != 0 ) {

        ret = 1; 
        }
    }

    return ret;
     } 
}
```

The program has to display the same things (without the permissions) as "ls -al". So far so good, if I compile it with "gcc -std=gnu99 -o list_dir list_dir.c" and execute the program with "./list_dir" I am getting the same result as "ls -al" and it looks like this :

```
 username    1599    Fri May  1 20:43:57 2015    list_dir.c
```

However if I run the program with something like : "./list_dir /home/username/Downloads/" I am getting this :

```
 32727   0   Sun May  8 07:09:04 4461391     selection_sort.c
```

As you can see, the program can't get the right information about the Username, the size of the file and the year. Also this information is appearing thanks to the else case of the if(pwd != 0) statement. If I don't have the else case, the program is printing out only the files, for which it can get the correct information. Also if I remove this if statement and also the if statement :

```
 if ( (stat(current_directory->d_name, &my_stat) ) == 0 )
```

I am getting a segmentation fault.

So my questions are : 
1.What am I doing wrong. I know that I am doing something wrong, because as a hint for the homework I have an example run of the program and also a hint that I can use "stat, lstat, readlink, getpwnam, getpwuid, strftime".

2.Is there any way to get the username with stat() and with the User-ID only, or it's only possible with getpwuid?

Comment: what about stepping through it with `gdb`?

Comment: `gdb` is a good idea, but may initially indicate an access violation substantially downstream from the actual cause of the issue.  `strace` would probably be even more effective, as it will show the ENOENT on the stat() call.

Comment: each directory entry needs to be check to determine if it is a sub directory or the end of a directory list or a regular file or a special file or a link, etc

Comment: the code is not handling the condition when stat() fails

Comment: why is this statement: '#include <dirent.h>' listed twice?

Comment: for human readability, suggest indent 4 spaces after each opening brace ';{' and un-indent before each closing brace '}'   be sure to use spaces and not tabs, as each editor/wordprocessor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here,

```
    if ( (stat(current_directory->d_name, &my_stat) ) == 0 ) {
       pwd = getpwuid(my_stat.st_uid); // Get User-ID
    }
```

What happens if `stat()` fails? `pwd` would have uninitialized value or incorrect value set from previous iteration.

The reason why `stat` would fail, `current_directory->d_name` contains only the file name whereas `stat` expects a fullpath. So you need to prepend the directory name to the file and pass it to `stat()`. You are only passing the filename right now.

Something like:

```
   char buf[1024];
   errno = 0;
   snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s/%s", dirname, current_directory->d_name);
   if ( (stat(buf, &my_stat) ) == 0 ) {
     ...
   }
   else {
      printf("%s: %s\n", buf, strerror(errno));
      // exit here or continue to the next entry in the directory 
      //depending how you wish to handle failure
   }
```

and handle the error in case `stat()` fails.

You also have one other `stat()` inside the loop which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using the char[] and snprintf fixed the problem. While reading about stat(), I probably missed the part, that it is expection the full path to the file.

Comment: You're welcome. I just saw you asked about getting uid: No, `stat()` can't give information about the username. So you approach to use `getpwuid` is OK. However, you could store UIDs (and respective usernames) so that you don't have call `getpwuid` if the UID is already in your list. It probably doesn't matter in your toy example but something to note.