# C trouble with stat

Tags: c, stat

In my program stat is only working for a current directory. Can any one please help me with this.

even though I am passing parameter from main it is only working for current directory.
and source path is good it is printing correct path which I have passed from the main.

```
    DIR *dr;
    struct dirent *cur;
    struct stat fi;
    long int total_size = 0;
    dr = opendir(source);
    char *name;
    printf("%s\n\n\n", source);
    if (!(dr))
    {
       perror("opendir()");
       return(1);
    }

    while (cur = readdir(dr))
    {
        if(cur->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
            if(stat(cur->d_name, &fi) == -1)
            {
                printf("error \n\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%s  ",cur->d_name);
                printf("%ld  ",fi.st_blocks);
                total_size = total_size + fi.st_blocks;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\ntotal_size = %ld \n", total_size);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you provide current output and expected output?

Comment: this line: 'perror("opendir()");' will not give an accurate presentation of any problem with opening a directory.  This is because a call to to printf() is between the call to opendir() and the call to perror() and printf() can modify the contents of errno.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29993938/1275169

Comment: Thank you :) I  confused because of I am getting correct values for current directory but now I gt it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cur->d_name only contains the file name.

to get a 'stat()' outside the current directory,

need to prefix with the path string.

Also need to check if the returned struct from readdir() 
is a file or a sub directory.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `stat` expects a file path but `d_name` is just the file name.  You can find a working example of how to use `stat` with `d_name` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877110/how-to-determine-directory-or-file-in-linux-in-c/30877241#30877241)